# AS 3 simple ease

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, tween

How can I move an object and be able to physically see it when it is moving? Not just disappear and appear on a different location like it would be using the following code.

> buttonL2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, left);
>
> function left(event:Event):void{
>
> ```
>       box_mc.x =241.5;
> }
> ```

This is going to move myObject to any location specified, but again I want to be able to see it when moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you are just setting it's X position when some button is pressed, when you need to change X into an EnterFrame event, like this:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);

function move(event:Event):void{
      box_mc.x -= 5
}
```

Your box_mc should move left 5 pixels accordingly with your framerate.

---

You can use a easing library to that easily. I strongly recommend [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/).

Comment: TweenNano would work just as well here, Greensock is fantastic

Comment: I said "TweenMax" because is how the library set is often called, including Lite, Nano, etc.

Comment: I've always just called it Greensock - but I wasn't trying to be particular, just pointing out that since he had a really simple request, that Nano would probably be easier than Max, take up less file size, etc.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I am getting a bit sick of people constantly suggesting some tweening engine.  Sure they rock, but it won't help the OP to understand what he is doing.

Kircho to move an object with a really easy tween I suggest the following code in an onEnterFrame event for your object to move:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
var xGoal:Number = 100;     //::  The target X destination for your object
var yGoal:Number = 100;     //::  The target Y destination for your object
var smothness:Number = 10;  //::  Smoothness factor for movement.  The lower the  value the faster the movement.

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
      box_mc.x += (xGoal - box_mc.x) / smothness;
      box_mc.y += (yGoal - box_mc.y) / smothness;
}
```

Will move/ease your box object to the desired location with a set smoothness.

Answer (score 1):

You can install any of the 437 available tweening engines
or you can add a few lines of code

set up a variable that holds the destination value

```
var dest:Number = 241.5; // this is what gets updated on mouse click
```

on enterframe event for box:

```
function onBoxEnterFrame(e:MouseEvent):void{
  if (dest != box_mc.x){
    var easeNum:Number = 0.4 // between 0 and 1, the higher the number, the slower the transition
    box_mc.x = box_mc.x * easeNum + dest * (1-easeNum);
  }
}
```

you can add a few more lines to snap the position when it is close (less than 0.1 difference) or use a more linear change where you adjust incrementally like `box_mc.x += 5;` until it matches the dest number