# Target Smooth Following

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm wondering today how to make a canvas element follow another canvas element smoothly. For example, I'm trying to make a game where a canvas element continually follows the player (which can be moved using W, A, S, & D) smoothly. I had an idea to use the Pythagorean theorem to check for the closest & fastest way to move from Point A (the canvas element) to Point B (the player). However, I have no physical way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas or answers of how I could make a canvas element constantly follow a player as smoothly as possible so it reaches the player the fastest?

Here I have an example of a very bad way of following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Target Following Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <center>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
  </center>
  <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    if (fillCircle) {
      ctx.fill();
    } else {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
  var drawRect = function(x, y, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20)
  }
  //Moving Obstacle
  var Obstacle = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vSpeed = 0;
    this.hSpeed = 0;
  }
  Obstacle.prototype.drawOb = function(color) {
    drawRect(this.x, this.y, "Red")
  }
  Obstacle.prototype.follow = function() {
    this.y += this.vSpeed
    this.x += this.hSpeed
    if (this.x < ball.x - 9) {
      this.hSpeed = 1;
    }
    if (this.x > ball.x - 10) {
      this.hSpeed = -1;
    }
    if (this.y > ball.y - 10) {
      this.vSpeed = -1;
    }
    if (this.y < ball.y - 9) {
      this.vSpeed = 1;
    }
  }
  Obstacle.prototype.checkCollision = function(direction) {
    return (ball.x - ball.radius < this.x + 20) &&
      (ball.x + ball.radius > this.x) &&
      (ball.y - ball.radius < this.y + 20) &&
      (ball.y + ball.radius > this.y);
  }
  // The Ball constructor
  var Ball = function() {
    this.x = 20
    this.y = 20
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
    this.radius = 10;
  };
  // Draw the ball at its current position
  Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
    circle(this.x, this.y, 10, true, "Black");
  };
  Ball.prototype.reposition = function(reX, reY) {
    this.x = reX;
    this.y = reY;
  }
  // Update the ball's position based on its speed
  Ball.prototype.move = function() {
    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;
    if (this.x < 11) {
      this.x = 11;
    } else if (this.x > width - 11) {
      this.x = width - 11;
    } else if (this.y < 11) {
      this.y = 11;
    } else if (this.y > height - 11) {
      this.y = height - 11;
    }
  };
  // Set the ball's direction based on a string
  Ball.prototype.setDirection = function(direction) {
    if (direction === "up") {
      this.xSpeed = 0;
      this.ySpeed = -2;
    } else if (direction === "down") {
      this.xSpeed = 0;
      this.ySpeed = 2;
    } else if (direction === "left") {
      this.xSpeed = -2;
      this.ySpeed = 0;
    } else if (direction === "right") {
      this.xSpeed = 2;
      this.ySpeed = 0;
    } else if (direction === "stop") {
      this.xSpeed = 0;
      this.ySpeed = 0;
    }
  };

  function simulate() {
    var prev_ball_x = ball.x;
    var prev_ball_y = ball.y;
    var prev_fol_x = follower.x;
    var prev_fol_y = follower.y;
    ball.move();
    follower.follow()
    if (follower.checkCollision()) {
      ball.setDirection('stop');
      follower.vSpeed = 0;
      follower.hSpeed = 0;
      follower.x = prev_fol_x;
      follower.y = prev_fol_y;
      ball.x = prev_ball_x;
      ball.y = prev_ball_y;
    }
  }

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ball.draw();
    follower.drawOb();
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }
  // An object to convert keycodes into action names
  var keyActions = {
    37: "left",
    38: "up",
    39: "right",
    40: "down"
  };
  // The keydown handler that will be called for every keypress
  $("body").keydown(function(event) {
    var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
    ball.setDirection(direction);
  });
  $("body").keyup(function(event) {
    ball.setDirection('stop');
  })
  setInterval(function() {
    // separate drawing and simulating phases
    simulate();
    draw();
  }, 10);
  // Create all the Objects!
  var ball = new Ball();
  var follower = new Obstacle(400, 100);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The least distance between A & B is a line. See the duplicate [Q&A}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561041/comparing-x-y-of-two-positions-on-a-canvas/27561396#27561396) to see how to use linear interpolation.

Comment: @markE: One of the two dupe targets for this question seems to have been deleted. As a gold badge holder, could you please edit the dupe list to fix that? Or better yet, reclose this e.g. as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849185/moving-an-object-along-a-straight-line-at-a-constant-speed-from-point-a-to-b instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note: i haven't really inspected your code...
But hopefully I understand your question correctly. And if I do, the solution could be pretty simple.

The most simple and fast way is to move the canvas element in a straight line to the player, without the help of mr Pythagoras. For that you need to know the player's position (x, y), which you do.

I took an easing function from an AS3 question, but it's the same for JS: [AS 3 simple ease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261783/as-3-simple-ease)

On every update, ease the follower to the position of the player:

```
follower.x += (player.x - follower.x) / delay;
follower.y += (player.y - follower.y) / delay;
```

**Example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz11ug7L/2/)**

It isn't a drop-in fix for your script, but hopefully it's helpful

Comment: Sorry, but I want a constant speed when it follows

Comment: @Cool123 So remove the delay. You could even use [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) to get the direction the follower can to move and multiply it by some constant. Play around with this code a bit and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how that''s going to work. Please provide an example

Comment: @Cool123 Just like I said. [Get the sign of the change and multiply by a constant.](https://jsfiddle.net/b84f7140/)

Comment: But that's not moving in the smoothest way

Comment: @Cool123 No one is going to just spoon feed you your perfect solution. You've got ways of approaching the problem and if you learn about normalizing a vector then you can get perfectly smooth animation. But you have to do some of the work yourself and technically this all meets your requirements.

Comment: @MikeC That example was the one I had exactly before in the other [duplicate] What happened was the follower moved diagonally into either the x axis or the y axis then moved toward the player. Unfortunately, that is not the smoothest way to move and also exactly what I did but coded differently